# Oil in the cooling system due to failed oil cooler

Tags: engine, cooling-system, diesel, dodge, ram

My 2014 Ram Eco Diesel's oil cooler failed and injected 1 to 2 quarts of oil into my cooling system. The dealer flushed the cooling system several times and replaced all hoses, oil cooler, radiator and thermostat. I still get small amounts of oil in the coolant reservoir. Will the oil degrade the coolant? Can it be bad for the engine?

Answer (score 2):

Is the oil still leaking into the coolant reservoir ? If so then yes it will eventually affect the cooling of the internals of your car once enough oil gathers in the reservoir.

If not and it's only a small amount(say a thimble full) then it won't do any damage in the long run to leave it in there although the dealer would probably recommend you flush it a few more times to get rid of the small amounts of oil.